# Why can't I map new Array(3) into an array of new values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to understand the **why** behind this:

```
var a = new Array(3);
var b = a.map(function () {
  return 'b';
});
```

results in

a: `[ , , ]`

b: `[ , , ]`

When I would expect b to result in `['b', 'b', 'b']`.

---

In further investigation, I discovered that if i were to do `a.push('a')`, I'd have `[, , , 'a']`.

And after the map function, `b` would become `[, , , 'b']`.

What's going on here? Why do these allocated cells behave differently from the initialization? I was originally expecting this to act as it would if it was an array literal, `[undefined, undefined, undefined].map(fn)`

Comment: I assume you meant `return 'x'` in your function `b`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222501/how-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array-of-arbitrary-length

Comment: javascript map function always return value which is in iterating array value only. Your array 'a' is empty of length 3. So it is returning same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** does not invoke the callback for indexes whose values aren't defined.

From MDN docs:

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
>   array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback
>   is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values;
>   **it is not invoked for indexes that are undefined**, those which have
>   been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

Comment: Good ole sparse arrays. TIL!

Comment: To be honest, I looked up the docs after seeing your question and TIL too! ;-)

Comment: haha awesome @techfoobar. If I only I did that too ;)