# Using new Array() to initialise an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to you `Array.prototype.map` method on an array of given length to initialise it with the objects. Note that I do not intend to any kind of loop here.

I had an idea to this as

```
cells = Array(numberOfCells).map(() => new Cell());
```

However, this does not work. Could somebody point out why and suggest a solution of a similar kind?

Comment: `Array.from({length: numberOfCells}).map(() => new Cell());`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737901/why-cant-i-map-new-array3-into-an-array-of-new-values, but use `Array.from(numberOfCells, () => new Cell())` nowadays.

Comment: I needed to do `Array.from({length: numberOfCells}).map(() => new Cell());` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cells = Array.from(numberOfCells, () => new Cell());
```

**edit:** *However, @Ryan was the first to point it out in the comments*